# Missing fonts for photoshop cs6 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: photoshop

I have installed photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04 with Wine1.7 but missed fonts. How to add fonts for it!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually search for the missing fonts using in your PSD file in the internet and then install them in your Ubuntu system.

To install fonts, just drop them into the hidden folder `.fonts` in your home folder or double click on font files one by one and click **Install Font** button.